# Error creating Ad via Facebook Marketing API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to create Ad via Facebook Marketing API.
Last step - Ad creation not working, and I can't find issue.

Here is code for Ad creation:

```
/**
 * @param RequestContract $request
 * @param Ad $runner
 * @return ResponseContract
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function run(RequestContract $request, AbstractCrudObject $runner): ResponseContract
{
    $this->configureCreative($request);
    $runner->setData([
            AdFields::NAME => $request->getItem('[ad][name]'),
            AdFields::ADSET_ID => $request->getItem('[facebook][adset_id]'),
            AdFields::CREATIVE => $this->creative,
    ]);

    $graphResponse = $runner->create(array(
        Ad::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED,
    ));

    return new ResponseGraph($graphResponse);
}

private function configureCreative(RequestContract $request) : void
{
    $linkData = new AdCreativeLinkData();
    $linkData->setData(array(
        AdCreativeLinkDataFields::LINK => $request->getItem("[ad][link]"),
        AdCreativeLinkDataFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => [
            'type' => AdCreativeCallToActionTypeValues::APPLY_NOW
        ],
        AdCreativeLinkDataFields::PICTURE => $request->getItem('[ad][image_url]'),
    ));

    $adCreativeObjectStorySpec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
    $adCreativeObjectStorySpec->setData(array(
        AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => $request->getItem('[ad][page_id]'),
        AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA => $linkData,
        //AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::INSTAGRAM_ACTOR_ID => ??? TODO add?
    ));

    $this->creative->setData([
        AdCreativeFields::TITLE => $request->getItem("[ad][title]"),
        AdCreativeFields::BODY => $request->getItem("[ad][message]"),
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $adCreativeObjectStorySpec
    ]);
}
```

With testing out requests I figured out that issue comes from `AdCreativeLinkDataFields::PICTURE` field in configuration.

When testing with some sample image 450x450 pixels - it is working.
When trying to pass real image with dimensions 1200 x 628 pixels (as facebook recommends) I'm receiving exception

```
FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException: Unsupported post request.
```

I've tried to resize this image to 628 x 628 - same error.
Tried to host it on different servers - no effect.

Tried with curl:

```
curl \
  -F 'name=Trial Company ' \
  -F 'adset_id=xxxx' \
  -F 'creative={"title":"Trial Company Inc","body":"xxx","object_story_spec":{"page_id":"xxxxxxxx","link_data":{"link":"link","call_to_action":{"type":"APPLY_NOW"},"picture":"link"}}}' \
  -F 'status=PAUSED' \
  -F 'access_token=xxxxxx' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=xxxxx' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_{id}}/ads
```

Getting error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AtGSfGrLe42"}}
```

Without any explanations why this error occured.

**UPDATE**: Created AdImage for current image - no errors occured. Tried to use `image_hash` in `LINK_DATA` instead of `picture` - same error occuring.

Comment: Not all campaign types support APPLY_NOW so that might be causing the error. Trying removing the CALL_TO_ACTION from the AdCreativeLinkData to test if that is the issue.